# Why compiler showing error

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading, overriding

Following is code

```
class Hotel {
 public int bookings;
 public void book() {
    bookings++;
 }
}

public class Test extends Hotel{
 public void book() {
    bookings--;
 }

 public void book(int size) {
    book();
    super.book();
    bookings += size;
 }

 public static void main(String... args) {
   Hotel hotel = new Test();
   hotel.book(2);  // Compiler show error
    System.out.print(hotel.bookings);
 }        
}
```

> **Erorr:**  method book in class javaapplication1.Hotel cannot be applied to given types;
>
> required: no arguments
>
> found: int
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

**Why compiler is complaining? which rule of Method Overloading/Overriding  compiler is applying?**

*Your response will be Appreciated !!!*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`hotel` is of type `Hotel`, which **doesn't have** `book(int)` method.

If you want to call `book(int)` you need to change (or cast) `hotel`'s type to `Test`

```
   Test hotel = new Test();
   hotel.book(2);  // No error
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler sees `hotel` has the type `Hotel` and the `Hotel` doesn't have a function of `book(int)`: but if we cast it to `Test` and invoke `book(int)` on it:

```
((Test)hotel).book(2);
```

We won't have an error. The behavior can be explained from [jls:15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)  section.

Answer (score 1):

You are using overloading which is a compile time polymorphism. So when the compiler sees 
    hotel.book(2);
it expects the Hotel's version of book method (remember its compile time). Since the hotel's version of book method does not contain any arguments, it considers this call as invalid and hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

You are making the object of `Hotel` not `Test` and calling the function `book(int)` which is a methog described in `Test`.

The methods of `Test` is not available to the objects of `Hotel`. If you use:

```
Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
hotel.book();
```

then it is fine, for using `book(int)`, you should have made an object of `Test`.

```
Test hotel = new Test();
hotel.book(2);
```

As `Test` has a method `book(int)` which is not overriding the super class method. Therefore, you should make an object of `Test` in order to access `book(int)`.

> Object of super class can only call those methods of child class which are overridden by the child class.

Answer (score 1):

Class `Hotal` is not aware of  the method `public void book(int size)` , and for invocation you are using the reference of `Hotel`.

Runtime polymorphism is nothing but defining  a contract for all who implement the base class/interface. This enable objects to interact with one another without knowing their exact type.  In your case base class does not have contract for `book(int)` which is own property of sub classes.

As quick fix you can try some thing like this,

```
 if(hotel instanceof  Test){
       ((Test)hotel).book(2);  // Compiler show error
   }
```

or

```
  Test hotel = new Test();
   test.book(2);
```

How ever ideall, you should be declaring/defning this method in `Hotel` class

Answer (score 1):

Here we are actually using  the parent class hotels refernce o the child class object.
but the book(int) is only in child class so we cannot use parent refernce.
if there is a method book(int) in hotel class then it is okey and the child class method will override the hotel class.

either
1.Test t=new test();
t.book(2);
2.hotel class class have book(int) method then
Hotel t=new Test();
t.book(2)
Both cases child class method will work and in the second case child class override parent class book method